# How do you return a value if it exceeds a certain number?

Tags: javascript, counter, subtraction

I am making a app for a board game for school, the game is based on Game of the Goose. In this game once you are on a certain spot and you *exceed* the highest number it sets you back the value that is left. For example, if you are at 64 and you roll 4 you return to spot 66 because 67 is the highest number. I'm using a math.random and a math.floor to add a number to the player from 1 to 6.

*edit:

Here is the code i am writing, it's a bit sloppy though, sorry for that.

```
var players = [
{
    name: "Speler 1",
    positie: 0
},
{
    name: "Speler 2",
    positie: 0
},
{
    name: "Speler 3",
    positie: 0
},
{
    name: "Speler 4",
    positie: 0
}
];

var position = 0;
var currentPlayer = players[position];

function rolClick(){
if (position >= players.length){
    position = 0;
};
currentPlayer = players[position++];

var rollen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
if (rollen === 1){
    currentPlayer.positie += 1;
}else if(rollen === 2){
    currentPlayer.positie += 2;
}else if(rollen === 3){
    currentPlayer.positie += 3;
}else if(rollen === 4){
    currentPlayer.positie += 4;
}else if(rollen === 5){
    currentPlayer.positie += 5;
}else if(rollen === 6){
    currentPlayer.positie += 6;
}};
```

Comment: Please post any code you already have,  as this will make it easier for people to answer your question

Comment: `Math.min(rolled, 66)`...!?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

Something  like this..

```
function onRoll(this) {

    currentVal=this.value;
    x=Math.random();//Ensure you have your limitations of random number in place;

    newVal=currentVal+x;
    if(newVal>66)//whatever your limit
        return 66;
    else
        return newVal;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the variable that you are increasing is called current.

```
function getRandomBetween(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var highest = 67;
current += getRandomBetween(1, 6);
if(current > highest) return  highest-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This script do what you want (I think):

```
maxValue = 67
dice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
oldValue = 64

if(oldValue + dice > maxValue){
    alert("You reached the maximum. Your Value is set to " + (maxValue-1))
    newValue = maxValue-1
}else{
    newValue = oldValue+dice
}
```

You should read the if Statements...
here you can read and learn it:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp